# Documentation of available Ant tasks for Android?

Tags: android, ant

I just accidentally discovered the ant task for test coverage reports with emma.
I'm now looking for a target that only invokes the unit test and generates unit testing output. 
Is there a list with the available ant targets somewhere, or is it possible to look them up somewhere inside the code of the SDK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a list with the available ant targets somewhere, ...

You can get a list of all `ant` targets with `-projecthelp` and `-verbose`. While in the root directory of the project:

```
$ ant -projecthelp -verbose
```

The private ones show under the heading "Other targets:", but the targets with a leading dash are impossible to invoke from the command line. You can add a "wrapper" target to your `build.xml` and simply make it depend on the target you want.

I use ones like this for exposing the main targets to the IntelliJ IDEA platform:

```
<!-- Wrapper targets for setting up IntelliJ IDEA with Ant Build -->
<target name="Android clean" depends="clean" />
```

But you could also do something like:

```
<target name="Generate Resource Source" depends="-resource-src" />
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a list with the available ant
>   targets somewhere

Not that I am aware of. I can't even see how to get Ant to dump a list. :-(

> is it possible to look them up
>   somewhere inside the code of the SDK?

They're on your development machine in `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/$API/templates`, where `$ANDROID_HOME` is where you installed the SDK and `$API` is some Android version (e.g., `android-2.1`).

Comment: `ant -p` should dump a list of available targets.

Answer (score 1):

`ant help` would display all the available targets with detailed description.

Help target is at the end of **${SDK.HOME}/tools/ant/build.xml**